# how to pass the id as an argument in the laravel link

Tags: laravel

I am new at laravel and i am using the follow syntax to call the controller directly from the url. Now I dont know how to pass the argument in these link. Please needed your help for these.

```
Route::get('/pagelink', 'YourController@callMeDirectlyFromUrl');
```

And in the link i have written these:

```
<a href="{{action('YourController@callMeDirectlyFromUrl')}}">Link name/Embedded Button</a>
```

Now how to pass the id in these code.

Comment: did you mean `Route::get('/{pagelink}', 'YourController@callMeDirectlyFromUrl');` or something else? - `{pagelink}` will be considered as url parameter and will be passed to your `callMeDirectlyFromUrl($pagelink)`, thus you could add an array to [`action('YourController@callMeDirectlyFromUrl', ['pagelink' => 'some_predestined_url'])`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-action).

Comment: i want these for example www.domain.com/pagelink?id=1. Kind of these thing i want Bagus Tesa

Comment: first of all, put your expected url and how it should behave in your question - this can add more context to your question. Then, back to your question, you could do something like `public function callMeDirectlyFromUrl(Request $request)` in `YourController` and access your `id` through `$request->input('id')`, [here the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#accessing-the-request). As for generating the action url just like the example i gave you before, `action('YourController@callMeDirectlyFromUrl', ['id' => 1])`.

Comment: Ok thanks i worked. My Error Is solved I just should have to do is pass an agrument in  <a href="{{action('YourController@callMeDirectlyFromUrl','$id')}}"> and then in route code i have pass id like these Route::get('/pagelink{id}', 'YourController@callMeDirectlyFromUrl'); And it worked.

Comment: uh.. well.. congratulations.. although it's a bit different from what i explained. but i'm glad you sort it out..

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this :

```
Route::get('/pagelink/{id}', 'YourController@callMeDirectlyFromUrl');

<a href="{{action('YourController@callMeDirectlyFromUrl', ['id' => 22])}}">Link name/Embedded Button</a>
```